# How can I download file in xamarin with webview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I'm new in a Xamarin development. I hope that you can resolve my problem in a simple mode.
I've a crossplatform app developed with Xamarin and I want to download a file from a url.

I tried to download file using C# code but i can't do it (for crossplatform app) so I want to try other way. **I want to use a webview and download the file directly into the web view. the problem is that when i click the button "download" into the webview it do anything. can you help me in a simply way?**

**my webview is this:**

```
<WebView Source="https://download.cnet.com/Free-YouTube-Downloader/3001-2071_4-75219434.html/" x:Name="webv" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
```

**it is an example of url**

Answer (score 1):

You have some plenty choices. But here's 2 of them. It's a simple one.

1. Using `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("Download link here"))`.
   This method is simple. It open the URL in client mobile web browser. And from there, the web browser will handle the background worker for download progress.
2. Using `WebClient()` class. Using this class, you'll can have your response in data type that you like maybe `string` or `byte[]`. Below's the sample:

```
var wb = new WebClient();

//Download as string
string x = wb.DownloadString("Download url");

//Download as byte[]
byte[] x = wb.DownloadData("Download Url");
```

From the return value of `x`, now you can rewrite it using `System.IO` to another file.

Note: These method is just basic. You can implement it in task, so your app will not hanging up while the download is in process.

Better approach: Via dependency service, download file from the native Android & iOS itself via `interface class`. you can check this one out: https://github.com/SimonSimCity/Xamarin-CrossDownloadManager#where-are-the-files-stored