# Downloading files through Xamarin WebView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a mobile application where I had to WebView a ***google drive*** page and when I click download, It simply does nothing.  `<WebView Source="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/184wYB9O-_8OF13QKoyeuMwP3bsxdUsdh"/>` [image: this is what it shows] I can't download or watch the video

also I cant use external browser or the application would just be useless

Comment: Does those help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58855652/5228202 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55550975/5228202

Comment: Thanks for your time but it actually didn't work